# Accessing asmx webservice returns page not found error

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis-6

I added a Webservice with a file Genomfaktureing.asmx to my web project, attached image here http://img42.com/e0xm0.

I call this webservice in an ajax call. It's working in my Visual Studio but getting page not found error after deploying to production server. I created a Webservice virtual folder in IIS manager pointing to the page with required permissions.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Webservice/Genomfakturering.asmx/UpdateSalesLine",
    data: { inoutorderno: salesOrderNo, externaltype: extType, externalno: extNo, quantity: quant },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus);
        alert(errorThrown);
    },
    success: function (msg) {
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "html",
            url: "/Templates/genomfakturering/ArticlesAdded.aspx",

            data: { orderNo: salesOrderNo },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus);
                alert(errorThrown);
            },
            success: function (data) {
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Code of the webservice

```
namespace se.dackia.web.Webservice
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "se.dackia.web")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class Genomfakturering : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod (UseHttpGet = true)]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }
        [WebMethod]
        public void UpdateSalesLine(string inoutorderno, string externaltype, string externalno, string quantity) 
        {
            // Get ext type from the string
            int exttype = 999;
            if (externaltype.ToLower().Equals("service"))
            {
                exttype = 6;
            }
            else if (externaltype.ToLower().Equals("rim")||externaltype.ToLower().Equals("tire"))
            {
                exttype = 2;
            }

            // converting string to decimal
            decimal quant = Decimal.Parse(quantity);
            try
            {
                // Adding new order line
                MSNavisionIntegration objMsNavisionIntegration=new MSNavisionIntegration();
                var newOrderLineNo= objMsNavisionIntegration.NewOrderLine(inoutorderno, exttype, externalno, quant);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }//catch
        }
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Classic ASP.

Comment: removed classic asp tag !

Answer (score 0):

In IIS, right-click the Webservice folder and Convert to Application.

Answer (score 0):

Change the following line of code:
url: "/Webservice/Genomfakturering.asmx/UpdateSalesLine",
 to something like

url: "~/Webservice/Genomfakturering.asmx/UpdateSalesLine" OR

url: "~/Genomfakturering.asmx/UpdateSalesLine"

as per your directory structure in your web application.